# HTML Form with input type 'Image' not responding to click

Tags: html, image, forms, onclick

In one of the cells in my table, I have an image. The idea is that when the user clicks on this image, a php script it supposed to run. The image displays perfectly (as does everything else), but there is no response to the click event.

```
<td id="btn_delete"
    <form action="delete_item.php">
        <input type="image" src="images/delete.png">
    </form>
</td>"
```

I'm thinking that maybe there is no onclick event here??? As I read the documentation, it seems to say that there is. Am I just doing something wrong or is there something about using an image in a form that won't allow for a click event? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I see is you are missing a right arrow on the first td:

```
<td id="btn_delete"
```

Should be:

```
<td id="btn_delete">
```

Comment: Ack! Wow. That's all it was. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :) Please mark this as the correct answer when you get a chance.

Comment: Done. SO just made me wait a few minutes before I could mark it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a click event for the image

```
<input type="image" onclick="someFunction()" src="images/delete.png">
```

The missing closing bracket on the `td` might also interfere with the your form

Comment: It was just the missing >. Doh!